How to run a long time running operation and give progress feedback on the UI?
I want to implement a simple way to execute a long time running operation (i.e. a sync from a central server database to a local one on the device) and have a visual feedback on the UI of the progress.
The operation could be triggered by a modal content page (Navigation.PushAsync), so that the user cannot do anything else during the sync (apart from canceling, but this is not included in the sample), and at the same time he can have a cue on the operation progress.
The operation itself is implemented in a class that raises events for signaling its progress.
I'm a MAUI newbie, and I've struggled for some days before finding a tricky working solution (UI was never updated!), trying to adhere as much as possible to MVVM.
I would like to know if there are better and cleaner way to do this.
Here the implementation (using the CommunityToolkit.MVVM):

a class used to exchange progress information

    public class ProgressInfo
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// progress percentage (between 0 and 1)
        /// </summary>
        public double ProgressPerc { get; set; } = 0;
        /// <summary>
        /// possible extra information related to the progress of the executing operation
        /// </summary>
        public object ProgressData { get; set; }
    }


a class that executes the long running operation (just a fake sample)

    public class SyncService
    {
        private ProgressInfo _progressInfo = new ProgressInfo() { ProgressPerc=0, ProgressData="Sync in progress..."};

        // event for communicating operation progress
        public event EventHandler<ProgressInfo> ProgressChanged;
        protected virtual void OnProgressChanged(ProgressInfo progress)
        {
            ProgressChanged?.Invoke(this, progress);
        }
        
        // main operation
        public async Task<bool> ReceiveFromServerAsync(DateTime StartDate)
        {
            //------ simulate long running operation ---------------------------
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                _progressInfo.ProgressPerc = (double)i / 10;
                OnProgressChanged(_progressInfo);
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
            //---------------------------------------------------------------
            return true;
        }
    }



a content page with controls used to show feedback

<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/maui"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SoEasyMobile"             
             x:Class="SoEasyMobile.UI.Generic.DataSyncPage"
             x:DataType="local:UI.Generic.DataSyncVModel" 
             Title="Sync Page"
             Shell.PresentationMode="ModalAnimated">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label Padding="40"
            Text="This is a sample sync page"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            FontSize="Title"/>
        <VerticalStackLayout Padding="50,20" Spacing="20">
            <Label x:Name="lblMessage" Text="{Binding ProgressMessage}" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontSize="Large" />
            <dx:RadialProgressBar Value="{Binding ProgressPerc}" 
                              StartAngle="135" 
                              SweepAngle="270"
                              WidthRequest="150"
                              Padding="0,30">
            </dx:RadialProgressBar>
            <Button Text="CLOSE" Clicked="btnClose_Clicked" IsEnabled="{Binding Finished}" />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>


a ViewModel used by the page

    public partial class DataSyncVModel : BaseVModel
    {
        SyncService Sync;
        IProgress<ProgressInfo> Progress;

        public DataSyncVModel()
        {
            Sync = new SyncService();
            Sync.ProgressChanged += Sync_ProgressChanged;
        }

        [ObservableProperty]
        double _progressPerc = 0;

        [ObservableProperty]
        string _progressMessage = string.Empty;

        [ObservableProperty]
        bool _finished = false;

        // this function can be called from the view in order to update the bound property (ProgressPerc)
        // that is used as a binding source in the view
        public void ChangeProgressPerc(ProgressInfo progress)
        {
            ProgressPerc = progress.ProgressPerc;
            Finished = (progress.ProgressPerc >= 1);
            if (progress.ProgressData != null)
            {
                ProgressMessage = progress.ProgressData.ToString();
            }
        }

        // this method can be called directly by the code behind in the view
        public async void DoSyncWithProgress(IProgress<ProgressInfo> progress)
        {
            Progress = progress;
            bool ret = await Sync.ReceiveFromServerAsync(DateTime.Now);
        }

        private void Sync_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressInfo e)
        {
            //IMPORTANT NOTE:
            //  if I directly change here the value of ProgressPerc property, the view is not updated
            
            // use the IProgress object in order to report the progress of the operation
            if (Progress != null) Progress.Report(e);
        }


    }


the code behind of the page

public partial class DataSyncPage : ContentPage
{

    DataSyncVModel vm;

    public DataSyncPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        vm = new DataSyncVModel();
        BindingContext = vm;
    }

    // OnNavigatedTo: the page is visible
    protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigatedToEventArgs args) 
    { 
        base.OnNavigatedTo(args);
        //IMPORTANT: here we are in the UI thread, so the lambda will be executed in the UI thread too
        var progress = new System.Progress<ProgressInfo>(progressValue =>
        {
            //call a method in the ViewModel, that will update the properties
            //that are used as binding sources in the view
            vm.ChangeProgressPerc(progressValue);
        });
        await Task.Run(() => vm.DoSyncWithProgress(progress));
    }

    private async void btnClose_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
    }
}   


Where is the code for the Report method?  And I’d suggest using a Timer for testing instead of Thread.Sleep

Hi @Jason, Thread.sleep is used solely for simulating a long time running operation, as what this operation does is not relevant for the main question. Anyway, the operation reports its progress through an event, this event is subscribed in the View code behind, that calls a method in the ViewModel using a System.Progress object ( (THIS is the only way I've found to guarantee that UI gets updated) so that the ViewModel can update the properties that are bound in the View.

Are you sure you are changing the property and not the value behind?

Again, please post the code of the Report method.

I was wondering if it was a MAUI issue. With your code,  I replaced RadialProgressBar with MAUI ProgressBar and then it worked. Please check.
